# Ionic cordova build failed on ios

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, push-notification

The following build commands failed:
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Check\ Pods\ Manifest.lock /var/root/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPNAME-amivxpiudfokodaybfmgyefynkvt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/EzSchoolApps.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/EzSchoolApps.build/Script-2E6AFD309B981ED6E1842543.sh
(1 failure)
xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65
[ERROR] An error occurred while running sub process Cordova.

```
    Cordova build iOS exited with exit code 65.
```

How to resolve above issue..?

Comment: mostly this code exists cause of pods... try updating pods version and if your xcode isn't on its latest version then do update it to the latest version...